# Count cells in a range that contain a value that exists in another string in Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, string, find, countif

I want to be able to count the number of records that contain a value that is contained within a string in another cell in Excel.

For example:

- My range contains the values red; green; yellow;
- String = red-green-blue
- Expected result = 2 as the string contains the first 2 values

The range may contain a variety of values, many of which may be contained in the string. I can't see how to combine a 'FIND' statement or similar with a COUNTIF statement. I've tried with various array formulas but cannot resolve.

Comment: Something like this should work: `=SUM(N(TEXTSPLIT(C2,"-")=A2:A4))` where `C2` = `red-green-blue` and `A2:A4` = `red;green;yellow` and even this would work `=COUNT(SEARCH("-"&A2:A4&"-","-"&C2&"-"))` given the scenario.

Comment: Unfortunately, the string will not be reliably split by any delimiter (and my version of Excel does not appear to recognise this operator either). Can you think of an alternative?

Comment: Will it be right to ask, to post few more examples with the expected outcome using **[Markdown_Table_Generator](https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/)** . Do post a copiable data so we can copy and use it. Also what is the excel version you are using?

Comment: =COUNT(SEARCH(A1:A3,A5)) where A1:A3 are values and A5 a string to search in would give answer 2. But there could be false positives dependent on requirements. Need more context

Comment: @Sg8107 if the `TEXTSPLIT()` version is not working on your end then use the `COUNT()` with `SEARCH()` which I had commented in the same comment.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.